# Connect to SQL server using groovy

Tags: sql-server, groovy

I am using sqlserver express , i want to do a connection from groovy and show the data on the console now i have an error and its not connecting. I decided to show what i have on here so we can debug together,

Code looks like this :

```
package com.connectgroovy

import groovy.sql.Sql

class GroovyConnectMssqlExample {

    static main(args)
    {
        def conn = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433","DESKTOP-V2G35NU\\SQLEXPRESS","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
        conn.eachRow("select * from [bonitasoft_jsonTest].[dbo].[people_data]"){
            println "${it.fullname} | ${it.perdiem}"
        }
    }

}
```

I get this as an exception error :

```
Caught: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-V2G35NU\SQLEXPRESS'.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-V2G35NU\SQLEXPRESS'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:197)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:2529)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:1905)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1893)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1045)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
    at com.connectgroovy.GroovyConnectMssqlExample.main(GroovyConnectMssqlExample.groovy:9)
```

What am i not doing right?

**PS**
I put the sqljdbc4.jar as a referenced Library. in eclipse

Comment: your login credentials are obviously wrong. Check if you can connect with those using some SQL client

Answer (score 1):

**Connection URL** - The url typically contains which server to connect to, what port and which database schema to work with. Example: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"

**Username and password** - The credentials for authenticating the connection. Example: username = user and password = password.

**JDBC Driver Class** - The JDBC driver class to use to connect to the database. Example for MySQL case: "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/test",
                "user", "password", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
```

For Window Authentication

```
def sql =Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;Database=myDB;integratedSecurity=true","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
```

Comment: My Sqlserver express was set to use windows Authentication.

Comment: In case it doesn't work it's because your user DESKTOP-V2G35NU\SQLEXPRESS does not exist...

Comment: It gives a totally different error this time May 11, 2019 11:06:34 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause :- no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path